# jQuery CORS turns GET into OPTIONS call

Tags: jquery, cors

This is a sample code which I use

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://myserver.com",
        beforeSend: function (xhr, data) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "xxxx");
        }
});
```

when I inspect this call in firebug I see OPTIONS and also I can't see Authorization code in request header.
CORS headers has been added to server side.

```
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60"); 
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");     
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Idea is to use pure jQuery if it's possible to perform such a queries.

Comment: What are you using on the server side? PHP?

Comment: @RononDex Java Spring, tried it from PostMan, and other tools works as a charm.

Comment: Why are you sending a GET request with a body?

Comment: A get request(with the Authorization code) should be sent after the options request, unless you get an access control error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preflight (OPTIONS) is occurring due to the fact that you are sending a cross-origin ajax request AND specifying an Authorization header with this GET request.

Also (this is not causing an issue) I would suggest removing the `contentType` option.  This doesn't make sense in the context of a GET request.  A GET request should not have any content.  All data should be included in the query string or, possibly, headers.

The Authorization header will not be sent with the OPTIONS.  You must acknowledge it server-side, and then the browser will send the underlying GET.  Read more about CORS at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Comment: Now I don't send it but still have same issue. I tried to send GET but in console it's turned to be an OPTION which doesn't have headers.

Comment: there is no GET call it's turned into OPTION somehow and header hasn't been set... Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He... authorization
Access-Control-Request-Me... GET
Connection keep-alive
Host stage.twingz.com
Origin http://localhost
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
x-insight activate

Comment: Again, your Authorization header cannot and will not be sent with the OPTIONS request.  There is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: yes I do, so what is the solution for it..or there is no solution to use GET + auth key?

Comment: Acknowledge the OPTIONS by returning a response with proper CORS headeres, then the GET will be sent with the Authorization header.

Comment: You need to acknowledge the OPTIONS request in your response. That happens on the server, not on the client.

Comment: you are about to say that there is no way to send single GET call from FE side?

Comment: What is "FE side"?  We are going in circles here.  The solution to your problem is simple.  Acknowledge the OPTIONS, then the GET will be sent.

Comment: got it, strange thing is in fact that I tred my service from runscope.com and it works from there, but not works from my jquery code, weird...

Comment: thanks this was helpful. Solution was to add filter in Spring and check if it's OPTION request and response proper headers, after that GET could be served.

Comment: Ironically, your suggestion to remove the `contentType` option "fixed" the behavior for me: The `GET` no longer became a `OPTIONS` request from Chrome. (However, I still had to fix the underlying root cause due to CORS, but it seems that a combination of CORS misconfiguration and the `contentType` was responsible for the GET->OPTIONS issue)