# Cross Origin Resource sharing issue even when all the CORS headers are present

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, cors

even though i have appended my service response with following provided **CORS Headers** :

```
resp.setContentType("application/json");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,accept,content-type");
resp.flushBuffer();
```

i am still getting below error in the console while trying to access some of  the **POST** web methods in the service through my AngularJS frontend.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.***.*.***:8080/abc/def/search/vehicleManufacturer. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.***.*.***:8085' is therefore not allowed access.
```

However within the same class, some **POST** methods without any payloads are responding perfectly. Any suggestions ?

EDIT--------->

Below is my AngularJS client screen code for calling the web method:-

```
getVehicleModel : function(searchData,$scope){
     $http({
         method:'POST',
         url:'http://192.169.*.***:8085/abc/def/search/vehicleModel',
         dataType:'jsonp',
         data:searchData

     }).
     success(function(data){
         console.log("vehicle model")
         $scope.vehicleModel = data.Response;

     });


},
```

Comment: Did your check if the response headers that you're adding in code are actually coming in response for that ajax call in DevTools ? Are you using any framework or just plain servlets ?

Comment: No, for the web methods in which m getting error, instead it's coming as OPTIONS as the method annd the response headers are missing in them.

Comment: it's plain raw servlets.

Comment: remove this "resp.flushBuffer();" once and check

Comment: can you post what you see in the network tab of your browser

Comment: As you're sending a POST request, I'm assuming you're doing these changes in doPost(), is that correct ?

Comment: Can you post the angular code, you're using to make the CORS request ?

Comment: @entre :- Check i have edited and added the network tab screen shots.

Comment: in the response headers, there is no access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Can you tell the `Content-Type` you see in request headers for the call that is failing ?

Comment: @entre: yeah, but actually you can see i have added it in my code.

Comment: @Arkantos :- I am wondering too what is making it fail specifically this method and not all without the payload one's.

Comment: @Reena: Still not working.

Comment: @Akash.. the problem is preflighted requests, have a look at my answer for more details

Comment: One more thing, you're setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to true, so make sure you set that header in your ajax request as well

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188956/jquery-cors-turns-get-into-options-call

Comment: I guess this is the 1000th duplication in this topic.

Comment: @inf3rmo: indeed, but believe me i went thru most of them before posting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is [Preflighted Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) in CORS.

From the Mozilla docs,

> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first
>   send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the
>   other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe
>   to send.  Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may
>   have implications to user data.  In particular, a request is
>   preflighted if:
>
> - It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used    to send request data with a Content-Type other than
>
>   - application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
>   - multipart/form-data
>   - text/plain
>
>   e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
> - It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header    such as X-PINGOTHER)

As explained above, even though you're making a simple POST request, the Content-Type in your request is `application/json` which is different from the 3 types mentioned above, so it's considered as a Preflight request and an OPTIONS request is fired before your actual POST request.

You can solve this by implementing `doOptions` in your servlet, just add the headers there and it will work :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Thanks, [HttpServlet.doOptions](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The preflight (OPTIONS) is occurring due to the fact that you are sending a cross-origin ajax request AND specifying an Authorization header with this GET request.

Also (this is not causing an issue) I would suggest removing the contentType option. This doesn't make sense in the context of a GET request. A GET request should not have any content. All data should be included in the query string or, possibly, headers.

The Authorization header will not be sent with the OPTIONS. You must acknowledge it server-side, and then the browser will send the underlying GET. Read more about CORS at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS .

Comment: If POST is used to send data to the server, the Content-Type of the data sent to the server with the HTTP POST request is one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain

Comment: I don't think HTTP is limited to POST in multipart or x-www-form-urlencoded. The [Content-Type Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) is independent to the HTTP POST method (you can fill MIME type which suits you).